# Warning: Unknown event handler property `onHeaderClick`. It will be ignored

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I am creating Higher order components for passing some props with another component. But getting the warning for Unknown event handler property.

```
 export class TableHeaderRow extends React.PureComponent{
     render() {
            const customCell = WrappedCellComponent(Cell,this.props.onHeaderClick, this.props.isMasterChecked, this.props.onTableCheckBoxselection);
            return (
                  <TableHeaderRowBase
                        cellComponent={customCell}
                        rowComponent={Row}
                        contentComponent={Content}
                        titleComponent={Title}
                        showSortingControls={true}
                        sortLabelComponent={this.props.sortLabelComponent}
                        groupButtonComponent={(data: any) : any => null}
                        showGroupingControls={false}
                        {...this.props}
                    />
            )
        }
    }

const WrappedCellComponent = (WrappedComponent, onHeaderClick,checkIfMasterChecked, onTableCheckBoxSelection) => {

    class HOC extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent 
                    {...this.props}  
                    onHeaderClick={onHeaderClick} 
                    onTableCheckBoxSelection={onTableCheckBoxSelection}  
                    checkIfMasterChecked={checkIfMasterChecked} 
                   />;

        }
    }
    return HOC;
};
```

Events are working, but I am getting error in chrome devTool (i.e. Warning: Unknown event handler property `onTableCheckBoxSelection`. It will be ignored.)

Answer (score 40):

This basically happens when you pass a prop with a name starting with `on`, regardless of its case. React assumes and tries to bind it with javascript events like onClick, onKeypress, etc

Comment: I rename on prefix to handle but the error changed to 'next-dev.js?3515:25 Warning: React does not recognize the `handleMinimizeClick` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `handleminimizeclick` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.'

Comment: in my case my problem resolved by preventing my parent prop passed to child resizable div using this code: `delete resizableProps.handleMinimizeClick;`

Comment: my issue was strange, two methods used, onHide and onConfirm. onHide works, and onConfirm failed. Renaming to lowercase worked but I decided to clone and remove the onConfirm from cloned. 
`const modalProps = Object.assign({}, props); delete modalProps.onConfirm;` then my button works without warnings `onClick={() => { props.onConfirm(); modalProps.onHide(); }}`

Answer (score 11):

The [error](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html) is well documented:

> The unknown-prop warning will fire if you attempt to render a DOM
>   element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM
>   attribute/property. You should ensure that your DOM elements do not
>   have spurious props floating around.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had already explored about "Unknown Prop Warning". But the problem is I am just passing action as props nothing different. You can see.

Comment: what's in the render of TableHeaderRowBase ? maybe it contains a DOM element where some props is explicitly setted or destructured with ...this.props

Answer (score 5):

Found the correct answer in another post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50196327/1734744
The problem was with passing props from parent to child using {...props} which may unintentionally pass the parent's event handlers to the child.

Also, I was passing the {...props} to a div (the container of the child component) and my custom event handlers were not recognized by div (native html tag)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, this happens because `if you attempt to render a DOM element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM attribute/property`. I needed a generic way of stripping all unknown props before spreading them onto an HTML element.

Custom hook:

```
export const useKnownPropsOnly = <T extends HTMLElement>(
  element: T,
  props: Record<string, unknown>
) => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    return Object.keys(props)
        .filter(key => key in element)
        .reduce<Record<string, unknown>>((acc, key) => {
          acc[key] = props[key];
          return acc; 
        }, {});
  }, [props, element]);
}
```

Implementation:

```
export const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => {
  const propsR = useKnownPropsOnly(document?.createElement('div') ?? {}, props);
  return (
    <div 
      {...propsR}
    />
  );
}
```