# Warning: Unknown event handler property `onValueChange`. It will be ignored

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know this question has been asked before. I've gone through solutions I've seen but none has worked for me unfortunately. Would really appreciate an extra set of eyes to help me see where I may have gone wrong.

Thanks

```
<div>
    <Input
        style={{ maxWidth: '200px', marginRight: '8px' }}
        data-type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        onValueChange={(Value) => {
          setFilter(Value);
        }}
        value={filter}
      />
</div>
```

EDIT

As requested here is some more information about the Input prop.

```
export interface InputProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
    [key: string]: any;
    type?: InputType;
    bsSize?: 'lg' | 'sm';
    state?: string;
    valid?: boolean;
    invalid?: boolean;
    tag?: string | React.ReactType;
    innerRef?: React.Ref<HTMLInputElement>;
    plaintext?: boolean;
    addon?: boolean;
    className?: string;
    cssModule?: CSSModule;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried with Value all lowercase, so it looks like `onValueChange={(value)...`

Comment: @N.Tasikj Hi, yes it was originally lowercase, saw a suggestion online that said change it to uppercase which is why it's like that now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Unknown event handler property \`onHeaderClick\`. It will be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945281/warning-unknown-event-handler-property-onheaderclick-it-will-be-ignored)

Comment: @DerekLawrence Thanks but no that didnt work :(

Comment: Can you show the Input component code ?

Comment: Please, share a reproducible example of your code

Comment: Also if you could share the library that `Input` is imported from, that would be great.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Answer (score 0):

The attribute for a value change is `onChange` (not `onValueChange`).

```
<div>
    <Input
        style={{ maxWidth: '200px', marginRight: '8px' }}
        data-type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={(value) => {
          setFilter(value);
        }}
        value={filter}
      />
</div>
```

As convention, function parameters should start with a lowercase letter, so as you can see I've changed case on the provided arrow function.

To understand this, you should have reviewed the documentation and followed the inheritance chain back through `InputHTMLAttributes` to `DOMAttributes` until you found the definition of the handler attributes.  There you will see there is no `onValueChange`, but `onChange`.

Also, a simple Google search through [this up](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onchange-events-with-examples) as a set of example of how to process change events.  RTFM ;-)